# open a link (like href ) is an USSD menu?

Tags: android, ios, ussd

Does is possible to open a link (like href in HTML) is an USSD menu?

User get USSD menu in theis startphone, which contains a link.

```
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

Are standard modern smartphones (IOS, Android), by default, able to open a browser when user 'touch' this link?

I expect the same behavior when I click url inside SMS, WhatsApp, etc.

Comment: I am so sorry this never got an answer.